# Capture mouse events in a Winforms button derived control

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent

I have a winforms control derived from Button, whose purpose is to display some dialog. 
So, the control can be "activated" by *tabbing* or by a mouse click according to the application state. Forcing tab access is required under some circumstances, to ensure previous fields are filled. 
Therefore, I need to "capture" mouse clicks on it, so to allow or disallow the mouse event according to the application state. 
To trap the tab key, I override OnEnter() and it works ok.
I also overrided OnClick(), OnMouseDown() and OnMouseClick() at no avail: the program control is always silently passed to the OnEnter() method. 
The debugger never stops in the OnClick() or OnMouse*() methods, so I cannot signal the event origin and prevent the core execution when needed. 
Could someone help? Of course, I don´t like to trap the windows message queue; some previous experiences were not happy.
TIA

Comment: are you setting handled = true some where?

Comment: Kindly, post your code [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51162587/edit) and tell us what your expected result is and what exactly does not work. I read your question 3 times and I still have no idea what you're asking. Always check your question against [this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/4934172) to make sure you get help easier and faster.

Comment: Steve: all those methods receive a lean EventArgs argument, which have no "Handled" member or like.

Comment: Ahmed: no code was relevant, because my question was conceptual. As you can see, Steve understood it and asked me some more questions.

Answer (score 1):

Using simple message pump filtering, as described here (https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/304777/how-to-temporarily-disabling-mouse-clicks-on-a-vb-net-form) with a class like this

```
// relevant usings...
using System.Security.Permissions;
...
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class MouseFilter : IMessageFilter
    {
        protected static bool inEffect = false;
        public static bool ActiveFiltering { set { inEffect = value; } }
        const int LButtonDown = 0x201;
        const int LButtonUp = 0x202;
        const int LButtonDoubleClick = 0x203;

        [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
        public bool PreFilterMessage( ref Message m )
        {
            if (!inEffect)
                return false;
            bool result = false;
            switch (m.Msg) {
                case LButtonDown:
                case LButtonUp:
                case LButtonDoubleClick:
                     result = true;
                     break;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The static property ActiveFiltering provides a way to enable/disable mouse clicks filtering as required.
Of course, the Program class must execute 
     **Application.AddMessageFilter(new MouseFilter());**
but, being inEffect = false, it don´t interfere normal general mouse operation.
My control disables the mouse when required, and takes care to left it enabled otherwise.
The solution is not perfect, but is what´s possible. The worst drawback is that while the control cancels the mouse clicks, no one can go to other control or the window self.